# Relationship between links

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

How do I find relationships between $$ lk(L),\; lk(mL),\; lk(rL),\; lk\Big(m \big(r(L)\big)\Big),$$ for any arbitrary oriented link $L$, where $m$ denotes the mirror and $r$ denotes the reverse.

So far I have found the linking number 'lk' for a certain knots but don't know how to generalise it. With the diagrams I've drawn I found that $lk(L)=lk(rL)$ and $lk(mL)=lk(m(r(L)))$ but does this hold for any arbitrary oriented link?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, your question will be downvoted and closed unless you [edit] it to show us what you are trying and where you are stuck. Ask just one small question at a time, not "how do I find all about all these relationships?".

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Does $lk$ denote the linking number? (Are we assuming $L$ has exactly two components?) What constitutes a "relationship"?

Comment: Did you also find $lk(L)=-lk(mL)$? If so, I think you found all the relationships.

Comment: Yes, I found that $lk(L)=lk(rL)=-lk(mL)=-lk(m(r(L)))$. Does this cover all relationships?